# I want to parse json , but unsuccessful. Can any one check my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a php page which print this from the database

```
[{"sha_id":"2","sha_text":"This is 1st sha."},{"sha_id":"4","sha_text":"this is 2nd sha"}]
```

now i want to extract each variable out of this.. after googling for a while i got this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://xxxx.com/android_sha/index.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var landmark = '<h1>'+item.sha_id+'</h1>'
                + item.sha_id+'</p>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                alert("error");         
        }
    });
});
```

but it always alert error for me. I could be something wrong at `$.each(data, function(i,item){` but can't figure out what should be the correct format.

Comment: If it runs `alert("error");` that means the `success` callback was never ran.  Does the server output JSONP correctly?  Remember JSONP requires the JSON to be wrapped in a function.

Comment: As a beginner to json I'm not sure that server output the JSONP correctly or not. I am simply following this tutorial http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/ and thats what all json code it return after viewing the source code. ( which r ill formated in a single line. )  php code use to create the json out put r simply these  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $records[] = $row;
}  echo json_encode($records);

Comment: JSONP is not *actually* JSON.  JSONP is a "hack" to get crossdomain data.  JSONP is actually JavaScript file.  It should contain a function call like: `callback([{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}])`.  `callback` should be replaced with the value of the `jsoncallback` parameter.

Comment: Oh Great ... Thanks Alot ... all the problem was my confusion between JSONP and JSON .. I got it working now. Really thanks Alot. Been messing with this 3 hours already :'(

Comment: Yeah, JSONP is kinda weird.  Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) isn't *actually* JSON.  JSONP is a "hack" to get crossdomain data. JSONP is actually JavaScript file.

You need to wrap the JSON in a function call.  In your example, you're sending the `jsoncallback` callback, so you need to wrap the JSON in the value of that.

```
$callback = $_GET['jsoncallback'];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $records[] = $row;
}
echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
```

Comment: Thank you . my not clear understanding between JSON and JSONP cause the problem.

Comment: You're welcome.  JSONP can be a little weird.  I consider it kind of a "hack".  Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @cjmling Ensure you select Rocket's answer as the correct answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: @HighwayofLife: ah ok. I was trying to vote up.. Which i could not. I actually have to click "correct" sign. Now i did.

Comment: @cjmling: You need [15 rep to vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). :-)

Answer (score 3):

If the alert("error") is triggered, it doesn't mean that the $.each function failed, it means that jQuery was unable to load the url specified or there was another problem with the ajax request. That triggers the error function, which alerts the error message.

Check that the request is working correctly, such as by using Chrome's developer tools to look at network traffic. If the page returns a non-200 status code, that is why the success function isn't triggering.

Comment: also make sure the response is a valid jsonp response

Comment: @Ericson578 : how do i make sure that is it a valid jasonp response? .. the jason reponse are exactly same as what i put in the question. ( they r all in single line ) after viewing the source code of the page in browser

Comment: @cjmling the way jsonp works is when you make the script request you add a ?callback=functionname to the request. The resource returned should be a script that calls functionname(params). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP